# boost filesystem suprious errors (temp_directory_path returns <Bad Ptr>)

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm trying to get the current temporary folder using Boost:

```
boost::system::error_code error;
auto tmp_path = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path(error);

if (boost::system::errc::success != error.value())
{
    std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
}
```

While investigating the value of the tmp_path during visual studio 2013 debug session it seems that the value of the tmp_path is incorrect - VS displays `{m_pathname=<Bad Ptr>}`.

The following code also fails with the exception "string too long", which may be related to the issue:

```
std::string tmp_file_str("test");
boost::filesystem::path tmp_file(tmp_file_str);
```

Boost was recompiled locally with the msvc toolset:

```
cd boost-folder
bootstrap
.\b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=release link=static,shared threading=multi --with-chrono --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-system --with-thread --with-test
```

Environment:

- Windows 8.1 Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600 x64
- Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because of a coincidence of two factors:

- boost libraries linked dynamically and without autoloading (BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK;BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
- linked boost libraries are in the release mode but the project is in the debug mode

Recompiling boost with `variant=release,debug`, specifying `-gd-` libraries in the linker properties and adding `-gd-` dlls to the path resolved the issue.